# How can I migrate my Ubuntu installation from LVM2 to RAID5?

Tags: boot, lvm, raid5

I stumbled upon [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72099/migrate-an-entire-volume-group-lvm2-to-raid5), but I do not think this is a duplicate since I'm under the impression that the OP in this question is not running under a live session.  I, on the other hand, have booted to an Ubuntu live USB drive for this operation.

I have an Ubuntu installation where everything lives on an LVM2, save for a `/boot` partition.  Thus far, I have done the following:

1. Created and mounted RAID5 array as md0
2. Mounted the current LVM, such that it's contents (along with `/boot`) can be accessed in `/media`

I would like to do the following:

1. Move my entire installation from the LVM2 to the RAID5 array (I think `rsync -avx` is the correct way of doing this)
2. Make it so that I can boot from the RAID5 array (i.e. move `/boot`?)

**My questions are as follows:**

1. Is `rsync -avx` the correct approach for moving my installation?
2. Do I need to copy `/boot` to the RAID5 array or to each of it's constituent discs?  If so, how can I achieve this given that I am in a live Ubuntu environment?

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to run LVM on top of mdraid RAID5, or alternatively use LVM's built-in RAID5? Both of those would have very easy data migrations (online, even). ... actually, the other question pretty much covers LVM on RAID5. No reason you can't do that from a live USB.

Comment: @derobert, none in particular aside from a general desire to keep things simple =)  Moving to LVM-on-mdraid is fine by me.  Would you mind explaining how it's done, bearing in mind that my questions about how to handle /boot still stand?  Thanks!

Comment: The steps in the other question ought to work. You may need to do a `vgscan` first if the Live USB hasn't found your vgs, but I suspect it has. Your copying of boot will look different, as you don't need to do the `mount --move` trickery. There is also LVM's built-in RAID (which in the case of raid5, is implemented with mdraid...)

Comment: @derobert, the copying of boot is where I remain somewhat confused.  Which parts apply to me?

Comment: I'll put that in an actual answer... And of course, you can also ignore the `mdadm --create` in the other question, because you've already done that.

Comment: Ok, I think I've got all the steps in my answer now. I left out "edit fstab" originally, fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, everything except for `/boot` & update initramfs is the same. I'll assume that your old boot is `/dev/sda1`. These steps should look familiar if you've ever used a live CD/USB as a rescue disk:

```
# mount /dev/vg0/root /mnt      # or whatever your vg/lv name is.
# mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev    # make these available inside of /mnt
# mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
# mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/mnt
# chroot /mnt                   # this switches into your installed system
```

You should now how a shell inside of your installed system. (Note: if you have any other critical directories on separate partitions, such as /usr or /var, go ahead and mount them. Remember to unmount them later in the cleanup.) Your old boot is mounted in `/mnt`, so just copy everything over:

```
# ( cd /mnt && tar c ) | ( cd /boot && tar vx )    # cp -a  would work, too
⋮ lots of output ⋮
```

Go ahead and edit `/etc/fstab` to comment out the entry for `/boot`, since it will no longer be on a separate filesystem. Then continue:

```
# update-initramfs -k all -u    # this will take a while if you have a lot of kernels
⋮
# dpkg-recofigure -plow grub-pc # I'm assuming you're running a Debian- or Ubuntu-like system
```

For the most part, you get to hit enter through the prompts from dpkg-reconfigure. Pay attention to the last prompt, when it asks you which disks to install on—you probably want to install on each of your RAID5 disks.

Finally:

```
# exit         # gets you back to the Live USB root
# umount /mnt/mnt
# umount /mnt/proc
# umount /mnt/sys
# umount /mnt/dev
# umount /mnt
```

I haven't actually tested this, but I've done it enough times. Please forgive any typos (or better yet, feel free to edit and correct.)

Comment: Thanks so much!  I'm moving the LVM now and I'll accept when everything is done.